# Enabling new API to already published Gsuite APP

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We already have our G-suite market place APP published and enabled with the below API

1. Google Drive API
2. Admin SDK API
   Now we want to enable the new API which is "Drive Activity API"

Wanted to know the impact of enabling the new API. Will this have any effect with existing APIs for our customers? And any other impact? Please assist.

Thankyou.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.
I am summarising the steps that we are going to follow for enabling new API and adding the scopes related to that API for our G-suite market place which is already in use.
1. Can we add the 2 scopes without publishing and authorising the Cloud-lock commercial Apps :   No

2. Can we enable Drive Activity API without publishing and authorising the Cloud-lock commercial Apps :  No

3. Is there any impact on the existing scopes and API  accessibility while doing the 1 and 2: No

Comment: Action plan for enabling the Drive Activity API  
1. Enable the Drive Activity API in Library-> console.developer.google.com
2. Complete the verification of 2 new scopes 
3. After verification is completed, add 2 new scopes in Google Workspace market place SDK by selecting the Cloud lock project ,  follow the steps mentioned in https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/manage-app-listing
3. Republish the Cloud lock commercial APP
4. Ensure the customers Authorise the new scopes added.

Comment: Please let me know if I am missing on any of the steps. for verification I am following the steps mentioned in https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#zippy=%2Csecurity-assessment%2Csteps-for-apps-requesting-sensitive-scopes%2Csteps-to-prepare-for-verification 
and sections below  
Verification Steps for apps requesting sensitive scopes
Steps to submit your app for Verification

Answer (score 0):

There should be no issue when adding another api in your existing app but you might need to **publish** the app again and ***request for a new OAuth verification*** to access the newly added API.

### Reference

[Update or unpublish an app listing](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/manage-app-listing)

[OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)

Comment: Thank you for replying.

So once I submit the APP after verification and adding scopes as per " Update your app listing"

What are the exact steps needed to be performed by our Customers of our Gsuite APP?
Will they get notified to do install the APP again?  
Will they get notified about the new scopes added and API enabled?